# Constant assemblies remapping in MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, .net-assembly, mvvmcross, base-class-library

I'm using MVVMCross for a while now. It's working great but I have these disturbing messages in my output window telling me there is maybe something wrong:

```
The request to load the assembly System v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
The request to load the retargetable assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to System.Core v2.0.0.0
The request to load the assembly System.Core v2.0.0.0 was remapped to v3.5.0.0
The request to load the assembly mscorlib v2.0.5.0 was remapped to v2.0.0.0
```

It's, I think, something about how PCL assemblies work, but I cannot elaborate more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is just debug output from Xamarin's CLR runtime as it loads PCLs and that it isn't a problem.

If you search for `xamarin The request to load the retargetable assembly System.Core v2.0.5.0 was remapped to System.Core v2.0.0.0` you find several hits about this, including several Xamarin Bugzilla entries - 
https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=xamarin+The+request+to+load+the+retargetable+assembly+System.Core+v2.0.5.0+was+remapped+to+System.Core+v2.0.0.0

If you are worried or if this is causing performance issues, then since this is occurring inside Xamarin.Android/iOS closed source,then I'd suggest you try Xamarin support for help and assistance.